# Eclipse Scout Neon add new row with tab key

Tags: eclipse-scout, newrow

I would like to add new row in table field if I press tab on the last column of the last row.

If user press tab on cell (editable cell) it select next cell in row or go in new (existing) row. But I would like to achieve that if I press tab on last row with last column that this action would create new row. Currently it focus next button/field/... in form.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use something like this:

Add on the last Column a `execCompleteEdit` and check if you are in the last row

```
        @Override
        protected void execCompleteEdit(ITableRow row, IFormField editingField) {
          if (row.getRowIndex() == row.getTable().getRowCount() - 1) {
            // create row
            ITableRow r = row.getTable().addRow(getTable().createRow());
            //eventually you have to set values into cells
            //get first editable cell(in this case NameColumn) and request focus
            row.getTable().requestFocusInCell(getNameColumn(), r);
          }
        }
```

Comment: This is not a good solution, because if you click on last cell in last column and then click anywhere in form (so click away), then this method is triggered.